# Python - No module named pygst

Tags: python, ubuntu, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm using virtualenv on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.13, and I'm trying to get `import pygst` to work (I'm a complete Python noob).

I downloaded:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-python/gst-python-1.12.1.tar.xz

Compiled and installed with:
`./configure --prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV && make install`

However I still cannot `import pygst`:

```
>>> import pygst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygst
```

There's also no pip package that matches pygst. I must be missing something really simple, but I can't figure it out.

This does not help either, because it only affects the system Python installation, not virtualenv:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gst0.10 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

How do I install pygst with virtualenv?

Comment: Did you try using `sudo apt-get install <name_of_pacakge>` ?

Comment: http://www.techinfected.net/2017/01/how-to-install-python-gst-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: @code_byter Yes. This is not the system python installation. It's a virtualenv. Installing the `python-gst0.10` modules do not help.

Comment: `pip install`inside your virtualenv folder.

Comment: Another way mentioned here is to use the python interpreter of your choice: http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ - where you can specify your local python

Comment: There is no pip package for pygst.

Comment: Try to acrivate your virual environment with the `.\bin\activate` script, and then run `pip install` with your's package

Comment: @YuvalPruss I did that, but there does not exist a pip package for pygst. At least I cannot find one. `pip install pygst` -> `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygst`.

Comment: try to `apt-get install python-pip` in the activate mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the pygst module

```
sudo apt-get install python-gst0.10 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

Then if you want access it in you virtualenv you can make a symlink to your site-packages, just replace 'venv' with the foldername of your virtualenv.

```
cd venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glib
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gstoption.so
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygst.pth
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygst.py
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygtk.pth
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygtk.py
```

Comment: Ok. I was able to get this to work by accepting that I had to downgrade to pygst 0.10. Two additional changes were needed: 1) Compile Python with `--enable-unicode=ucs4`, 2) `ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi` in the `site-packages` folder. Thanks for your help.